# regex for routing in rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I am looking for a regex which can let me have a dot in the id in rails routes except the case when the format requested is xml or json, i.e.
http://www.abc.com/users/e.f.json should mean id=e.f and format=json
http://www.abc.com/users/e.f should mean id=e.f

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you give us more (and clearer) examples of input and your desired output.

Comment: `e.f` could be 'ef.gh`? any decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex:

```
/users\/(\w*\.\w*)(\.json|\.xml)?/
```

[See tested code here](http://www.rubular.com/r/MsKXpXUACa).